# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "ponerse como el tenazas"?

Tags: expresiones, historia

Hoy estaba comiendo una galleta en el trabajo cuando pensé: "Me estoy poniendo como el tenazas".

La expresión significa que estoy comiendo mucho y me está sabiendo bien rico, un poco en plan glotón.

Me gustaría saber de dónde viene, ¿cuál es su origen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si buscas la expresión en Google, los resultados parecen apuntar a un personaje andaluz del siglo XIX. Copio de [uno de ellos](http://reflexionesdemanuel.blogspot.com/2012/10/nuestra-lengua-ponerse-como-el-tenazas.html):

> **"Ponerse como El Tenazas"** = Comer mucho y bueno. El Tenazas" o “El Tenazas de Morón” fue un cantaor conocido por su voracidad y por su inclinación por el vino. Su verdadero nombre fue Diego Bermúdez Cala. Nació en Morón de la Frontera (Sevilla) en 1850 y falleció en Puente Genil en 1933.

Más información sobre el cantaor [aquí](https://tiempoflamenco.blogspot.com/2012/04/diego-el-tenazas-honor-y-deber-de-un.html) (donde se hace referencia al segundo apellido como Calas). No encuentro casos de la expresión ni en el CORDE ni en el CREA, pero en la hemeroteca de la Biblioteca Nacional de España aparecen algunos casos (en obras que no son de acceso público) partiendo desde la década de 1990.

Comment: O sea que la expresión sería relativa al vino, al menos originalmente.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' en realidad parece que se usa más bien para "comer mucho y bien". Curiosamente, aunque el personaje es de mi tierra no tenía yo constancia de la expresión.

Comment: O podr'ia ser por las dos cosas, no?